# How to add spacing before and after a cdot?

Tags: spacing, amsmath

I'm having the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsmath}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert #1 \rVert_2}

\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
\norm{\cdot}=...
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to add a little space before and after the dot in the norm, because it's a bit crushed between the vertical lines now. Is there a command with the same output as `\cdot` that does this automatically or should I insert the spacing manually (with `~` for example) each time?

Comment: `\norm{{}\mathrel{\cdot}{}}` does the trick quite nicely.

Comment: You can insert a thin space with `\,` or a thick space with `\;`.

Comment: You won't find a command that has the space built-in, I don't believe.  Manual space or relational spacing should be fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would go even further than Mico, why not embed the empty arg marker into the macro it self.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{mathtools,etoolbox,amssymb}
\newcommand\emptyarg{{}\cdot{}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\norm[1]\lVert\rVert{
  \ifblank{#1}{\emptyarg}{#1}
}
\begin{document}
\[
\norm{}: A \to B \qquad \norm{X}
\]
\end{document}
```

BTW: on CTAN the latest `mathtools` version now contain a tool to build the `L^2` norm, such that one does not have to add the `_2` manually all the time.

Answer (score 6):

You could define a new macro named, say, "`\widecdot`", that surrounds `\cdot` with thinspace (`\,`) on either side. Note: I wouldn't redefine `\cdot` directly, as this macro tends to be used internally by other macros as well.

Incidentally, your definition of `\norm` is a bit suboptimal since subscripts -- such as the `2` in your example -- aren't set quite low enough. It may be preferable to use the macro `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` of the [mathtools](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package; compare the output of the `\norm` and `\Norm` macros in the second equation below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert #1 \rVert_2}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\Norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\newcommand\widecdot{\,\cdot\,}
\begin{document}
\[ \norm{\cdot} \text{ vs.\ } \norm{\widecdot}\]

\[ \norm{\widecdot}\text{ vs.\ } \Norm{\widecdot}_2 \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's odd I event even thought there was a placement different between the two. Seems I got lucky ;-)

Comment: @daleif - I think the OP's definition of `\norm` generates the insufficiently-low subscript issue because it doesn't use `\left` and `\right` (or equivalent). Hence TeX doesn't "know" that the `2` subscript should be typeset a bit lower than usual as it follows a glyph (`\Vert`) that has a descender component.

Comment: But should it know from the fact what we are using `\rVert` that ought to to mark it as a closing fence. The only thing extra that `mathtools` do is to wrap it explicitly in a `\mathclose`.

Comment: @daleif - I think the use of the explicit `\mathclose` directive is the key. Compare the looks of `\lVert a\rVert_2` and `\mathopen{\lVert} a\mathclose{\rVert}_2`, in either inline or display-style math mode: Without the explicit `\mathclose` directive, the subscript is positioned without regard to the size of the preceding symbol. This holds for other fence symbols too, such as `)`, `]`, and `\}`...

Comment: @daleif it is not the `\mathclose` as you can test with `\mathopen\lVert a\mathclose\rVert_2` but the braces (which create a sub-formula) as you can test with `{\lVert} a{\rVert}_2`. Try also `{\lVert a\rVert}_2`.

Comment: So basically for an unscaled fence a subscript is generally placed a bit too cramped.

Comment: @daleif - I've discovered yet another wrinkle to this story: the "cramped" look of the subscript next to a math fence which hasn't been given an explicit `\mathclose` wrapper turns out to be specific to pdfLaTeX. In contrast, in LuaLaTeX (with the `unicode-math` package loaded), in such a situation the lower edge of the subscript ends up being typeset flush with the lower edge of the fence; this actually looks quite good to me. One could even argue that the subscript ends up being placed *too low* in LuaLaTeX if the closing fence has been wrapped in `\mathclose`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your remark about the norms. It looks a lot better now. Big vote up!