# How to write correctly $|.|$

Tags: math-mode

I'm sure this question is a duplicate, but I can't find the main question.

If I write `$|.|$` it doesn't appear with in my textbook, I wonder what is the correct way to do it.  I'm using it to try to write a function `$|.|: A \to B$`

Comment: It took me a while to understand what the notation means. Alright the `·` appears to be used as a placeholder/wildcard here → [Spacing around \cdot when used as a wildcard - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78165/spacing-around-cdot-when-used-as-a-wildcard) ■ [symbols - Placeholder for variable as in f(x, .) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47060/placeholder-for-variable-as-in-fx) ■ [math mode - Spacing around \cdot - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261724/spacing-around-cdot)

Comment: Or more closely related, [amsmath - How to add spacing before and after a cdot? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180313/how-to-add-spacing-before-and-after-a-cdot) ■ [math mode - Absolute value symbol with spacing - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632905/absolute-value-symbol-with-spacing/632925#632925) ■ [adjust $\cdot$ in math expression - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149829/adjust-cdot-in-math-expression/149844#149844)

Comment: This maybe a record, I had this problem today morning and this question helped me!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do define a command for this. I chose `\blank` as the name, you might prefer a different one.

Why? Because you want that `\blank` is

1. an ordinary math atom
2. dependable on the required style

Why condition 2? Because your new coauthor might prefer a dash rather than a dot, for instance, or you need to to comply with the house style of some big publisher.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\blank}{\mathord{{}\cdot{}}}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{|}{|}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{How not using a command might get things wrong}

\begin{enumerate}

\item \makebox[\width][s]{$|{}\cdot{}|\colon A\to B$}
\item \makebox[\width][s]{$|\blank|\colon A\to B$}

\item \makebox[0.8\width][s]{$|{}\cdot{}|\colon A\to B$}
\item \makebox[0.8\width][s]{$|\blank|\colon A\to B$}

\item \makebox[1.2\width][s]{$|{}\cdot{}|\colon A\to B$}
\item \makebox[1.2\width][s]{$|\blank|\colon A\to B$}

\end{enumerate}

\subsection*{Easy to redefine}

\begin{enumerate}
\item $|\blank|\colon A \to B$

\item $\abs{\blank}\colon A\to B$

\renewcommand{\blank}{\mathord{-}}

\item $|\blank|\colon A \to B$

\item $\abs{\blank}\colon A\to B$

\renewcommand{\blank}{\mathord{{}\operatorname{--}{}}}

\item $|\blank|\colon A \to B$

\item $\abs{\blank}\colon A\to B$

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Do you see why I don't recommend something like `{}\cdot{}`? The simulation of stretching for justification in the first part should clarify it: you don't want that the spaces around the lonely `\cdot` participate in stretching or shrinking for justification. The `\mathord` around the construction makes a subformula with frozen spacing *and* makes it impossible to use `\blank` outside of math mode. You can see that using `\blank` always produces the same symbol (consisting of the dot and of the space around it).

In the second part I show a couple of possible redefinitions of `\blank`.

[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell, `{\cdot}` will do the job as well. Is there any reason to use `\mathord{\cdot}` in favor of `{\cdot}`?

Comment: @antshar This would have smaller spaces around the dot than with `{}\cdot{}`, which might be a valid style decision; I'd prefer an explicit marker, but that's a personal choice.

Comment: I've never seen dash used as a placeholder in math for absolute value / norm so cdot is fine I think

Comment: @qwr I've seen used it as a placeholder in category theory books.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this?

[image]

Note that I've replaced `.` with `\cdot` and that I use `\colon` rather than `:`, since the latter is treated by TeX and LaTeX as a relational operator.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \DeclarePairedDelimiter macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}
$\abs{ {}\cdot{} }\colon A\to B$
\end{document}
```

Comment: See my answer for possible shortcomings of this approach.

Comment: Aside from the shortcomings, this answer uses `lvert` and `rvert` which I believe are better that `|` for typsetting `abs`. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498/mid-vertical-bar-vert-lvert-rvert-divides